# Open Colourbox/Jquery on Server control after postback C#

Tags: c#, jquery

Am having a problem trying to trigger linkbutton that on click needs to add value to viewstate then after post back open up colourbox. After post back the colourbox does not open unless you click linkbutton again.

```
<div id="modules-link">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="BT_AddModule1" CssClass="grey-bar popup" CommandArgument="1" 
        runat="server" onclick="BT_AddModule1_Click">Open box</asp:LinkButton>
</div>

protected void BT_AddModule1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton LB = (LinkButton)sender;
    ViewState.Add("PHNU", LB.CommandArgument);  
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", 
        "$('.popup').colorbox({ width: '80%', inline: true, href: '#modules' });", true);
}
```

Comment: After clicking the button, do a view source on the page that gets rendered - is there anything obvious in the html that would prevent the jquery call firing?